# Where can I find the source code of gitk?

Tags: gitk

gitk seems to have very nice interface design and whatnot. I really want to explore its source code. So where can I find it?

By gitk, I mean the one to view the repository history of git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with Open Source get it from the horses mouth - gitk is now part of the git distribution.

http://git-scm.com/download

```
git clone git://github.com/gitster/git.git
```

Comment: The page seems to have changed the official repo URL at some point in the last few years - it now points to https://github.com/git/git.  /gitster/git still seems to be in sync though.

Answer (score 7):

gitk lives in a subfolder of [git's official repository](https://github.com/git/git).

It's written in [wish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wish_(Unix_shell))/[Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl).  Its folder (at time of writing) can be found at https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/gitk-git, mostly contained in a single file called [`gitk`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/v2.24.0/gitk-git/gitk).

Answer (score 1):

gitk is its own source code, since it is written in tcl and tcl is a scripting language. Just open `/usr/bin/gitk` with the text editor of your choice. It seems to be contained in a single file.

Comment: On Windows, `gitk.exe` is inside `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd` folder. It looks like a binary application.